# How to merge two objects values in single object

Tags: javascript

hi i am facing some issue on this

```
let members={
    first_name:"sagar",
    last_name:"phani",
    birth_date:"31-06-1996",

}
let customers={
    first_name:"MERGE31",
    last_name:"MERGE32",
    birth_date:"MERGE33"
}
```

actually i have two objects so i need take member objects values and customers object values

and generate new object like this

```
{MERGE31:"sagar",MERGE32:"phani",MERGE33:"31-06-1996"}
```

can u please any one help to slove this issue

Comment: Will both customers and members have same keys always?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(members).map(([k,v])=>[customers[k],v]))` or `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(customers).map(([k,v])=>[v,members[k]]))`

Comment: Why is `MERGE33:"birth_date"`?

Comment: @TusharShahi   yes both customer and members have same keys always

Comment: @Andy why we beacuse we working with mailchimp integration node js with lambda and i made a mistake sorry its should MERGE33:"31-06-1996"

Comment: @Sagar Shouldn't it be `MERGE33:"31-06-1996"` instead of `MERGE33:"birth_date"`

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar yes its like that only sorry i will edit it..thanks for the good catch

Comment: Then the answer provided by Lovlesh works fine

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar yaa its working but i have one question , i need to take values only when keys are matching other wise not.beacuse in both the objects we have  same keys so

Comment: Edit your post to include such scenario

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful.

```
let output = {};
Object.keys(members).map(key => {
   output[customers[key]] = members[key];
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Lovlesh Pokra than u so much for helping me,once again thank u for u r help..

Answer (score 0):

```
let output = {};
Object.keys(members).map(key => {
   output[customers[key]] = members[key];
});
console.log(output);
```